# how to automatically open pdf file after dvi2ps2pdf in emacs

Tags: pdf, emacs, dvi, ps, sumatrapdf

i want to let emacs automatically open pdf file after i type `C-c C-c dvi2ps2pdf RET`, so i add the following code in my `.emacs` file

```lisp
;;dvi2ps2pdf
(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
 (list "dvi2ps2pdf" " dvips %s.dvi | ps2pdf %s.ps %s.pdf | SumatraPDF %o"
 'TeX-run-command nil t))
```

it works fine, well, until i find that it fails if the tex file, say, `foo.tex`, has `\usepackage{psfrag}` in it as follows,

```
% foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\[ e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\]
\end{document}
```

SumatraPDF would open `foo.dvi` instead of `foo.pdf`.

if i type `C-c C-n` and start all over, it works fine again, as long as i do not compile and produce a new `foo.div`.

after compiling and `foo.div` is created,

if i replace `%o`  with `%f`, `SumatraPDF` would open `foo.ps`

if i replace `%o`  with `%s.pdf`, `SumatraPDF` would open two broken files `foo` and `.pdf`

if i replace `SumatraPDF %o` with `start \"\" %s.pdf`, `Adobe Reader` will correctly open `foo.pdf`

this is frustrating. how can i edit the code to let SumatraPDF take over everything? and how to use those substitution `%o` `%f` `%s` properly? excuse me that i'm really inexperienced, but it seems that they belong to different conventions? thanks very much!

### UPDATE

---

with @giordano's help, i tend to believe that this is a inherent problem of `SumatraPDF` (`Adobe Reader` too, i think).

i think there's no problem on linux or mac. on windows, however, in `DOS` commands, i find that the following are the same, say,

- `copy foo.pdf bar.pdf`
- `copy "foo".pdf bar.pdf`
- `copy "foo.pdf" bar.pdf`
- ...

other external commands such as `dvips` and `ps2pdf` do not distinguish the cases, either. SumatraPDF, however, treats `foo.pdf` or `"foo.pdf"` as one same file, and `"foo".pdf` as two separate files `foo` and `.pdf` and even opens them.

i think that's why `SumatraPDF` always fails to open `%s.pdf`. it is a file name parsing flaw， if i'm right, `SumatraPDF` is not intend to open files like `.pdf` on windows system, and it should be able to detect that automatically.

p.s.

i also tried to manipulate the string `%s.pdf`(="foo".pdf) and tried to strip the double quotes in ways of `lisp` or `DOS` command. the quotes won't go away and i failed miserably due to inexperience.

do you guys have any ideas? thanks!

### UPDATE

---

thanks to @giordano, i gave a shot on `cygwin`. (i had `cygwin` install for doc view anyway, no trouble at all.) it turns out that `SumatraPDF` works completely fine on cygwin, i.e., it accepts file names such as `"foo".pdf`. so i decided to redirect all command line calls to cygwin. i added the following to `.emacs` file (see [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NTEmacsWithCygwin)),

```lisp
 ;; Sets your shell to use cygwin's bash, if Emacs finds it's running
  ;; under Windows and c:\cygwin exists. Assumes that C:\cygwin\bin is
  ;; not already in your Windows Path (it generally should not be).
  ;;
  (let* ((cygwin-root "c:/cygwin")
         (cygwin-bin (concat cygwin-root "/bin")))
    (when (and (eq 'windows-nt system-type)
         (file-readable-p cygwin-root))

      (setq exec-path (cons cygwin-bin exec-path))
      (setenv "PATH" (concat cygwin-bin ";" (getenv "PATH")))

      ;; By default use the Windows HOME.
      ;; Otherwise, uncomment below to set a HOME
      ;;      (setenv "HOME" (concat cygwin-root "/home/eric"))

      ;; NT-emacs assumes a Windows shell. Change to bash.
      (setq shell-file-name "bash")
      (setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name) 
      (setq explicit-shell-file-name shell-file-name)))
```

after that, `SumatraPDF` recognizes `%s.pdf` just fine.

there is one problem, though. `dvi2ps` runs differntly on cygwin and cannot proceed, i put the question [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348924/dvips-behaves-differently-in-windows-dos-and-in-cygwin).

p.s.

code of `SumatraPDF` has been improved to accomodate cases like `"foo".pdf`. hopefully we'll see how it work [very soon](https://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/issues/detail?id=2434).

Comment: If it's a bug you should really report it to Emacs (`M-x report-emacs-bug RET`) or AUCTeX (`M-x TeX-submit-bug-report RET`) instead of trying to work around.  If it will be fixed upstream, everyone will benefit, not just you `;-)`.

Comment: i think i'll try to report this to SumatraPDF first :)

Comment: One option would be to become more comfortable with command-line and set up your own function similar to my first example, which obviates the need to rely upon AUCTeX.  Another option would be for you to open up `tex.el` and take a look at `(defcustom TeX-expand-list . . .` and perhaps create your own variables that format file names in a manner that SumatraPDF likes.  You can customize your own variable in whatever format you like -- e.g., by using `split-string`, and `concat`.

Comment: In my first example, I used:  `(setq base-file (car (split-string (buffer-file-name) "\\.")))` and `(setq pdf-file (concat base-file ".pdf"))`.  If your `buffer-file-name` is `c:/davy/jones/foo.tex`, then `base-file` is `c:/davy/jones/foo`.  Then, `pdf-file` concatenates a `.pdf` onto the end of `base-file`.  This gives you a *.pdf file name that SumatraPDF likes.  My line of code `(start-process "displayline" nil sumatra "-forward-search" tex-file line pdf-file)` is shorthand for `C:/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe -forward-search c:/davy/jones/foo.tex [line-number] c:/davy/jones/foo.pdf`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is much simpler than what you've done so far: define a single command that runs `latex`, `dvips` and `ps2pdf`.  In this way, when `TeX-PDF-mode` is active the PDF will be opened by your default PDF viewer without any further change.  In your init file you can add something like this:

```lisp
(add-to-list
      'TeX-command-list
      '("dvi2ps2pdf" "%(latex) %s && dvips %s.dvi && ps2pdf %s.ps %s.pdf" TeX-run-command nil t))
```

I'm not familiar with DOS batch scripting, in UNIX shells `&&` is the logic AND, the following command is run if the previous one exits successfully, I don't know what's the batch analogous.

Comment: @giodano,great! thanks very much! the only thing i need to do is to stay in the `pdflatex` mode. btw, what if i want to perform this in the `dvi` mode and i do not want to switch to the `pdf` mode to open the pdf file, otherwise i would get the `dvi` file to open, or in the presence of `psfrag` package, the `ps` file will open in gsview?

Comment: @davyjones it wouldn't be a clean solution, but you can append `SumatraPDF %s.pdf` to the list of programs to be run by the `dvi2ps2pdf` command.

Comment: @giodano,saddly simply appending does not work... as i stated in the original question, that would cause `SumatraPDF` to open two broken file, say, `foo` and `.pdf`. i think we could define a function `viewpdf` first as found in [link](http://www.sylwil.eu/wikiss/?page=dotemacs), but i would not how to use it inside the double quotes again, do you have any suggestions? many thanks again!

Comment: @davyjones has the file spaces in its name?  Appending `&& okular %s.pdf` (Okular is my PDF viewer) works for me.  Try protecting the file name with quotes: `\"%s.pdf\"` instead of simply `%s.pdf`.

Comment: @giodano, sadly, it failed again... `SumatraPDF` will open two broken files, one with no name, the other with name `bar".pdf"`. if i use `SumatraPDF .\\%s.pdf`, `SumatraPDF` will open one broken file named `"bar".pdf`. it still fails if i change `SumatraPDF` to `AcroRd32`. is it because i'm using emacs+auctex on windows system?

Comment: @davyjones I don't know, I don't use AUCTeX on Windows systems, but I've never seen anybody reporting such problems.  Try to add this function to view PDF: `(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("View PDF" "SumatraPDF %s.pdf" TeX-run-discard-or-function t t))`.

Comment: @giodano, thanks for your patience! it occurred to me that someone else has actually encountered the problem before (see [link1](http://www.latexbuch.de/install-latex-windows-7/) and [link2](http://forums.fofou.org/sumatrapdf/topic?id=2608355)). i tested under linux, and your code works perfectly. under linux, `okular %s.pdf` is interpreted as `okular foo.pdf`, as is expected. however, under windows, e.g. `ps2pdf %s.ps` is interpreted as `ps2pdf "foo".ps`, and `SumatraPDF %s.pdf` is interpreted as `SumatraPDF "foo".pdf`. the problem is `ps2pdf` accepts this syntax while SumatraPDF doesn't.

Comment: @davyjones someone claims it's a bug in Emacs, see for example [Emacs lisp - problems with filename-string on win7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566045/emacs-lisp-problems-with-filename-string-on-win7).

Comment: thanks @giordano! i tried `cygwin` and it works great, see update. one problem `dvips` cannot find `psfrag.pro`, see [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348924/dvips-behaves-differently-in-windows-dos-and-in-cygwin)